# Add SSH keygen to Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keygen

On my remote server I generated the SSH keygen using `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and now, I'd like to add the SSH keygen to my Ubuntu computer.

It seem's not working using : `ssh-copy-id -f user@remoteserver.com`

Error message : `/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: failed to open ID file '/home/anthony/.pub': No such file`

Comment: You would typically run `ssh-keygen ...` on a *local* machine, then use `ssh-copy-id` to upload the public key from the local machine to the remote server.

Comment: And on the remote server I just need to run `ssh-copy-id` ? Because I don't know the host and username of my local machine...

Comment: You run `ssh-copy-id` on the same machine on which you run `ssh-keygen`.  Your *private* key does not leave the machine on which you generate it; `ssh-copy-id` copies the *public* key to a remote machine so that in future you can use your *private* key to authenticate to the remote machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to `ssh-keygen` on your **local** machine.
*Default path for keys*: **~/.ssh**

Copy local key to remote server
 `ssh-copy-id user@example.com` 

If your still having trouble, use the **full** remote path

   `ssh-copy-id user@example.com:/home1/user/`